# Linear algorithms for diet optimization with AWS RDS, Node.js, Ionic

Tags: mysql, node.js, algorithm, amazon-web-services, mathematical-optimization

I am looking to integrate a lieanr algebra optimization algorithm for recipe recommendations. I’m using AWS RDS for MySQL and using node.js to connect to an ionic mobile app.

I’m looking for the best way to program in an algorithm similar to this: https://www.linearprogramming.info/diet-problem-in-linear-programming-solved-with-excel-solver/

The goal of the algorithm is to pull historical data from a patients nutrition record; look at ingredients they have in their pantry and recipes can cook; suggest recipes via mobile app a patient can cook that optimize nutrition intake to fit within a patients specific goals.

Looking to see if 1) I can do this with my current stack 2) is their any plugin packages that can help and 3) any other recommendations to make it happen.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey John your question is not tech specific enough and is too broad. Suggest you do the implementation spike discover specific challenges snd then ask questions re those. Right now your question sounds like “can i create a website with javascript”...

Comment: Obviously you probably need an LP solver. Unless you are really brave and want to write your own one.

Comment: Are their any LP silver packages that I can integrate with? My issue is I know what I need I just don’t know where to get the right package to do what I need

Comment: Most LP solvers are available as either an executable or a DLL. You should be able to call them from either node.js or MySQL.